# Laravel file validation mimes for .obj

Tags: laravel, validation, mime-types

I want to validate .obj files when received by input type file. I am using the following code in the validator but it's not working. Any suggestions?

```
 file|mimes: .obj|max:2500
```

Comment: `mimes:obj`, not `.obj`.  https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-mimes

Comment: @Devon I changed it like you said and its not working! :/

Comment: @Devon I get this error
    {"file.0":["The file.0 must be a file of type: obj."]}

Comment: What is the file?  Is it  an application/x-tgif as described here https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types?

Comment: @Devon The file is Wavefront .obj

Comment: Read the Laravel docs...  the extensions used in the validator must match the Apache mime types.

Comment: give your form codes

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the validation `mimes:obj` didn't work for me too. So my solution was that instead of using laravel's validation, inside the controller, first detect the file's extension and then return the validation message. After the validation, I save the file. here is how I did this:

```
       if($request->hasFile('model3d_file')){

           $model_extension = $request->File('model3d_file')->getClientOriginalExtension();

           if ($model_extension != 'obj' && $model_extension != 'OBJ') {
               return response()->json(['success'=>false,'message'=>__('responses.file_format_should_be: ', ['format' => 'obj'])]);
           }

           .
           .
           .
       }
```